# Not convert string value to integer value

Tags: python-3.x

```
d =input().split("-")
y,m,d = int(d[0]),int(d[1]),int(d[2])
is_leap_year = (y%4==0 and y%100!=0) or (y%400 == 0)
c=d
for i in range(m-1,0,-1):
    c+=M[i]
    if i==2 and is_leap_year:
        c+=1
print(c)
```

Here variable y,m,d are integer variable but when i submit this code in online judge it throws "Line 3: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"2019' ".  Why?

Comment: It shows `"2019` in the error. It seems like you have a quote in front of the number.

Comment: How are you inputting the date format?

Comment: @Carcigenicate sir, when i run in my editor all is right. But online judge or online editor don't take it. They show me this error. What happens with my code i don’t understand.

Comment: @NurAminSifat They may be testing how well your code handles bad input. You'll need to add a `try` block to catch the error.